# How to remove "Standby Inactivity Message" ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, standby

how to remove the popup message from standby inactivity?

Because this message is more than annoying, it is still there when I wakes.

Using ubuntu 13.10 (upgrade from 13.04) with Unity

[image]

**TRANSLATION :**

POWER

Automatic Suspend

Computer will suspend very soon because inactivity

**EDIT [7-01-2013] :**
I believe we have found a solution on the ubuntu-fr.org forum. All credits to return Bybeu who created a script that literally removes the popup message. When I speak, I have not tested the script but if an expert could there have a look and give us his opinion, it would be appreciated.

You can find the info of Bybeu here to post # 13 http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=15691731#p15691731 or via [google translator](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=15691731#p15691731&act=url)

Comment: Need more info.  Like system, ect...

Comment: This message appear after upgrading ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 with Unity

Comment: Please translate the message shown in the image.

Comment: No one have a solution ?

Comment: Same problem here on two laptops after upgrading them from 13.04 to 13.10. Apparently this bug has been reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1232454